# Shell script execution in ssis

Tags: shell, ssis, executeprocesstask

I have a file with extention .sh(shell script).
I need execute this file in ssis using execute process task.
how can i do this.
Please help me!!!
Code inside  .sh file :echo SSIS test >>  /home/junaib/test/sql.txt  (for testing)

Comment: You need an environment with a shell interpreter. So you will need a Linux/Unix environment.

Comment: I have enabled WSL in my windows 10

Comment: So open a bash shell and run the script with ./ You will need to create a /home/junaib/test directory with the relevant sql.txt file in there or change the path in the script,

Comment: is it possibe to execute through ssis?

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled WSL and you sure that the commands work from command line then you can run the command on cmd.exe with the /c flag

```
Executable : cmd.exe
Arguments  : /c "BASH C:\SO\test.sh"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I am tried with above code, but unfortunately getting error for me.

Error:[Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "cmd.exe" "/c "BASH C:\temp\priya.sh"" at "C:\temp", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Comment: Argument: /c "BASH C:\temp\priya.sh"|
Executable: cmd.exe
Working directory :C:\temp

Comment: @junaib can you open cmd.exe and run the command? Exit code 1 means that the the bash command returned an error for some reason

Comment: Executed.Got error

C:\>/c "BASH C:\temp\priya.sh"
'/c' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Without the /c, please execute only **BASH C:\temp\priya.sh**